# How to export ext js 4.0 panel into image format?

Tags: javascript, image, pdf, extjs

I have number of grids on a panel in **Ext js 4.0** with some of the grids which have been **scrolled top or scrolled left**. I want to convert that panel along with all the grids into some image form like **jpeg**. Or even a **pdf** format. 
    For larger size of panel image can be distributed in number of different files.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try html2canvas https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas

Comment: you can try transporting the data in each grid to excel and then convert this excel file to pdf

Comment: @CD..-I will check html2canvas.

Comment: @BhandariS - I need the positioning of the grids to be exactly at the same position that I have created them in panel.

Comment: since you know the position..just place them in the pdf in the ame order or you can capture the order dynamically in integrate both conversion codes

Answer (score 0):

We use iText http://www.itextpdf.com/ to generate PDF on the fly and make it same as  the grid.
It is separate code though and does not use the grid. You just make it look same as the grid.